# Make event (hover,click) on oculus go or other controllers

Tags: aframe

I have a fairly vanilla example of aframe that on click changes the color of an entity. On desktop, everything works fine and such but on oculus go it does not. How can i make the events work with the same desktop cursor on oculus go and as well as make sure it works on all other controllers?

```
  <a-assets>
    <a-mixin id="cube" geometry="primitive: box"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="cube-hovered" material="color: magenta"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="cube-selected" material="color: cyan"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="red" material="color: red"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="green" material="color: green"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="blue" material="color: blue"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="yellow" material="color: yellow"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="sphere" geometry="primitive: sphere"></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity position="0 2.2 4">
    <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls>
      <a-entity position="0 0 -3"
                geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.2; radiusOuter: 0.3;"
                material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
                cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
        <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
             fill="forwards" from="0.2 0.2 0.2" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
        <a-animation begin="fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
             fill="backwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.2 0.2 0.2" dur="1500"></a-animation>
      </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="-3.5 1 0">
    <a-entity mixin="cube red">
      <a-animation begin="click" attribute="position" from="0 0 0"
                   to="0 0 -10" dur="2000" fill="both"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="0 1 0">
    <a-entity mixin="cube green">
      <a-animation begin="click" attribute="rotation" to="0 360 0"
                   easing="linear" dur="2000" fill="backwards"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="3.5 1 0" rotation="0 45 0">
    <a-entity mixin="cube blue">
      <a-animation begin="click" fill="forwards" repeat="1"
                   direction="alternate" attribute="position" from="0 0 0"
                   to="15 0 0" dur="2000"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="0 3 0" class="clickable" mixin="cube yellow"
            rotation="0 45 0" scale=".5 .5 .5"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

codepen:https://codepen.io/Absulit/pen/WEKjqm

Comment: It needs code and link to example that illustrates your attempt(s)

Comment: @DiegoMarcos my apologies. editing sec.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos done

Comment: FWIW, your code is an a very old A-Frame version 0.6.1. Use 1.0.4

Comment: FYI, a-animation has been deprecated use the [animation component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/animation.html#sidebar)

Comment: Okay let me try that

Comment: Are all controllers supposed to work out of the box?

Comment: Yes, see [laser-controls example](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/laser-controls/) Also read [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/laser-controls.html#sidebar)